# creating a unique column in Linux (more like an sql primary key?)

Tags: linux, bash, primary-key

so i am new to Linux and our instructor gave us this assignment, its fairly simple but I haven't been able to create a unique column for my 'employee code' (we need this in order to avoid duplicating codes) 
I tried two methods below

**Method 1**

```
    echo "Enter an Employee Code:
 read code
    if [$code uniq -u]
 then
    echo "Enter surname"
 read surname
    echo "Enter Other names"
 read other_names
    echo "Choose Gender"
    echo "f Female  m male"
 read gender
    case $gender in

         f) Female;;
         m) Male;;
         *) echo" that was not one of the choices"
           esac
    echo " Enter DOB"
 read dob
    echo "Enter Phone Number"
 read phone_num
    echo "$code   $surname   $other_names   $gender   $dob" >> details
```

else
     echo "Duplicate employee code"
     fi

**METHOD 2**

```
     echo "Enter an Employee Code:
 read code
     while [ $code -ne $code ]
 do
     echo "Enter surname"
 read surname
     echo "Enter Other names"
 read other_names
     echo "Choose Gender"
     echo "f Female  m male"
 read gender
    case $gender in
          f) Female;;
          m) Male;;
          *) echo" that was not one of the choices"
            esac
   echo " Enter DOB"
 read dob
   echo "Enter Phone Number"
 read phone_num
   echo "$code   $surname   $other_names   $gender   $dob" >> details
```

else
       echo "Duplicate employee code"

done

can someone please help? **method 1** doesn't recognize the "uniq" constraint while **method 2** keeps increments non-stop. thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Please tag with the scripting language you are using. And try to state clearly what the problem is, what input and output you expect.

Comment: The indentation is painful. Looks like a (ba|k|z)`sh` script (a shebang would help). It appears you're just outputting the columns (to a file). I don't see where you're pulling `$code`s out of the file to check against.

Comment: Sorry about the bad indenting, forgot to mention  its my first time asking a question here and I ddnt know how to use the indents, also i couldnt copy my original code from my vmware linux.

Comment: I am also not pulling $code from a file, the user types it in, then the script is supposed to check if it is uniq or not, if it is uniq, it moves on to the next echo otherwise it tells the user "duplicate code has been entered" and terminates

Comment: For homework problem you should ask your instructor/TA, who've got an understanding of what you know/expected to know. This is just so simple and boring that it's hard for us to give you hints or anything; but if we just show you the code, it defeats the purpose of assignments.

Comment: Thanks for your advice 4ae1e1, however the instructor refuses to help, I could easily jst declare code as a variable and increment to a certain value, but I don't want to do that because doing that means I know exactly the number of employees the "supposed company" has. I really wish this was sql or something, it would have been way easier

Comment: "The instructor refuses to help." I take that as a signal that you aren't supposed to get help from anywhere; your instructor didn't refuse to help just to have you ask on SO. Review your honor code if you have one in your institution.